# How to take the data (in for loop) that is output in the terminal and show it on a web page?

Tags: python, django

I want to make a page where text is entered, and then a function that outputs synonyms of words from this text.

My view.py is:

```py
def home_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.POST["translate"]
        print(text)
        translator = Translator() 
        translate_text = translator.translate(text, src='auto', dest='en')  
        print(translate_text.text)
        Text = translate_text.text.lower().replace('.', '')
        word_list = Text.split()
        # print(word_list)
        for word in word_list:
            synonyms = get_some_word_synonyms(word)
            kk_word = translator.translate(word, src='auto', dest='en')
            kk_word = kk_word.text
            if synonyms:
                print( kk_word, 's synonym is:')
                for synonym in synonyms:
                    # print(synonym)
                    translate_text = translator.translate(synonym, src='auto', dest='en')
                    
                    print("     ", translate_text.text)
                   
                    
        
   
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

I have this output in terminal.
Wanna make web page were you can see something like this.

Procedures and systems for identifying and eliminating malfunctions and malfunctions of equipment, networks and systems

procedures s synonym is:

```
  procedure
  process
```

systems s synonym is:

```
  system
```

identifying s synonym is:

```
  identify
  place
```

eliminating s synonym is:

```
  extinguish
  eliminate
  get rid of
  do away with
```

malfunctions s synonym is:

```
  malfunction
```

malfunctions s synonym is:

```
  malfunction
```

networks s synonym is:

```
  network
  web
```

systems s synonym is:

```
  system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the things you want to show  as context, and pass it to the template from the view.
Instead of printing them on the terminal.

```
def home_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    words = {}
    text = request.POST["translate"]

    translator = Translator() 
    translate_text = translator.translate(text, src='auto', dest='en')  
    
    Text = translate_text.text.lower().replace('.', '')
    word_list = Text.split()

    for word in word_list:
        kk_word = translator.translate(word, src='auto', dest='en')
        kk_word = kk_word.text
        words[kk_word]= []
        synonyms = get_some_word_synonyms(word)
        if synonyms:
            for synonym in synonyms:
                translate_text = translator.translate(synonym, src='auto', dest='en')
                words[kk_word].append(translate_text.text)

               
                
    

return render(request,'index.html',{'words':words})
```

Now you can access the words and their synonyms in the template.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I get some error:

words[kk_word.append(translate_text.text)]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Sorry I was rushing it should be words[kk_word].append(translate_text.text)

Comment: I dont know how exactly you will use it, but {{ words }} will give you all the words and synonyms you would have to then use them.